# Is this index algorithm worth anything?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have theorised a indexing algorithm (like a B-tree).

However, there's a mental block stopping me actually implementing it.

The algorithm comes in to forms:
form 1:

- A look up time of O(1) - O(log2(n))
- Each value in the index will have metadata associated to it that is of the size log2(n)*memory address size

form 2:

- A look up time of O(1) - O(log2(n)/2)
- Each value in the index will have metadata associated to it that is of the size log2(n)*2*memory address size

**Unlike B-tree/other index algorithms, there's no time penalty for a add/deletion**.

You can for example do a add, then do a search straight after (with no waiting in between).

You get a faster search at the expense of more metadata (memory) along with being able to insert/delete in real time.

You can also do sequential access/search sequential data values fast.

I can't find any other algorithm that has that attributes and time complexity.

If I can get it to work, I plan to sell it.

My question is; would this actually worth anything to anyone/or useful in any particular application?

Or is the amount of memory it uses too much of a deal breaker?

Comment: Usually commercial software projects are more viable when the use case is known.  However, implementing the algorithm may be very useful for your own purposes.

Comment: I would try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: 23 billion exabytes is constant memory. 23 billion years is constant time. Asymptotic bounds don't determine real world performance.

Comment: @melpomene True enough, but asymptotic bounds often provide a useful albeit rough guide to real world performance.

Comment: @JohnColeman “They provide a surprisingly useful heuristic.”

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah, but if the question is "*is the amount of memory it uses too much of a deal breaker?*" - well, we don't know how much memory it uses.

Comment: What elements are you storing? Integers, Strings? What kind of queries do you support over them? Membership queries? Prefix search?
As it currently stands it's impossible to have an idea of what you accomplished.

Comment: and BTW, what does "lookup time of O(1) - O(log2(n))" actually means? It ranges between constant and logarithmic time? It is constant minus logarithmic?

Comment: Seeing this bit: "O(1) - O(log2(n)/2)", I'd say go for it. Most probably it won't work from the first try, but this strange big-O notation hints that you will learn something in the process, which may be a good result in its own.

Comment: It means to, as in O(1) to* O(log2(n)/2) @gassa there's no need to be rude.

Comment: @EricSpam I'm sorry if it sounded as an insult for you. But you still show that you are not familiar with the notation. Perhaps you mean the number of some actions in the best and worst cases, respectively. However, O(x) is the same as O(x/2), and O(natural logarithm of n) is the same as O(binary logarithm of n), so people usually drop the constants there. That leads me to the conclusion that you still have something to learn. There are chances that your algorithm is indeed good and useful, but looks far more likely that the immediate value of your endeavor would be learning, not application.

Comment: @EricSpam That does not by any means imply that you won't get new useful algorithms working. It's a worthy goal indeed. Just be ready that it might not happen right now.

Comment: @gassa, OK, it was my misunderstanding. How comes O(x) is the same as O(x/2)??

Comment: @EricSpam [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is not the exact number of steps of some kind, it's asymptotic behavior of this number of steps.

Comment: You say "... there's no time penalty for a add/deletion". Does that mean you insert in zero time. Or is it constant time?